# Google Guava Cache not Caching

Tags: guava

I'm using Google Guice to instantiate the LoadinCache to use guava cache.

My binding is below:

```
   bind(new TypeLiteral<LoadingCache<SelectRequest, SelectCResponse>>() {})
        .toInstance(
            CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(1000)
                .expireAfterAccess(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .recordStats()
                .build(
                    new CacheLoader<SelectRequest, SelectResponse>() {
                      @Override
                      public SelectResponse load(
                          SelectRequest selectRequest) {
                        System.out.println("inside load method of cache : when cache not found");
                        return Select.read(selectRequest);
                      }
                    }));
```

And I'm injecting in my impl class below:

```
  @Inject
  public CeImpl(final LoadingCache<SelectRequest, SelectResponse> cache)
```

and in a method

```
SelectResponse res = cache.get(selectCeBlobOracleRequest);
```

When I test this code, the cache is not actually cache my records. What could be the issue here? It's always hitting the DB.

Do I have any wrong eviction policy?

Answer (score 0):

i was creating a new request everytime i sent to cache.
resolved this by creating single request instance.